# how to connect movesense to Azure iothub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, movesense

I am new working with Movesense and I would like to know how to send data from my Movesense device to Azure Iot Hub.

Is this possible? The idea is that the Movesense Device should send for example the acceleration data to IoT Hub. 
Could the Movesense Rest APIs being used to do this?

I would really appreciate id somebody has a clue or some instructions of how to do it.

Is there out there a tutorial of how get data form a movesense sensor?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about a tutorial specifically on connecting movesense sensors, but you can try to connect using our SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks

Answer (score 0):

The movesense sensor does not have internet connection so it cannot send data directly to the cloud. However there are many projects that use either a mobile app or Raspberry Pi as a IoT gateway to forward the data. For one such project that uses the Movesense sensor in beacon mode, see [raspi-gateway](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-raspi-gateway/src/master/).

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*